# SQLite functions using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

How to use `SQLite` function using `PreparedStatement`?

```
PreparedStatement stmt;
String query = "insert into Test values(?,?)";
stmt = conection.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(2, "date('now')");
```

`date('now')` is the `SQLite` function I want to use, but it inserts "`date('now')`" as `Text`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of achieving this is by changing your sql string, with this you may not need to set the date parameter anymore in your preparedstatement.

```
String query = "insert into Test values(?,date('now'))";
```

Now just you need to set the parameter 1

```
stmt.setString(1, <<param1 value>>);
```

Comment: This's embarrassing. Thanks